# Is mercury in barometer rises infinitely in satellite

Tags: fluid-dynamics, gravity, pressure

***Let suppose a satellite revolves around the earth. Air pressure inside the satellite is maintained at 76 cm of mercury, and i have a barometer of length 1 m initially***

as in space the gravity is zero and hence to equalise the pressure at the free surface of reservoir of mercury, the mercury in column has to rises upto 1 m.

Now if i modify this question by *constructing a tube of infinite length. So as g is zero, and to equalise the pressure at the free surface of mercury reservoir, the mercury in the column has to rise infinite length as* **pgh is always zero**

Is that thinking is correct ? Or not ?

Comment: In the gravity case, the rise is 0.76 m, not 1 m.

Comment: It is likely that the mercury will form small balls instead of a long continuous fluid, it will depend on the acceleration of the spacecraft and on the surface tension of the fluid with its container.

have a look here:
https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/research/news/Predict_Liquid2.html

Answer (score 1):

Well, "rise" is perhaps not quite the right word, as the gravity gradient is too small to be used to define up and down.

So it's the same as if you had a mercury vessel horizontal on earth.  If there's a pressure difference, the unequal forces will accelerate the mercury in the direction of the lower pressure.  This continues until the pressures equalize because there is no gravity gradient to provide an additional force on the column.